# Simpler alternative to simultaneously Sort and Filter by column in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filtering

I have a spreadsheet ([here's a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lyzRnq0RyLkB75-axsSFqARDto7e4CLydM3TEsqlagU/edit?usp=sharing)) with the following (headered) columns:

- A: Indices for a list of groceries;
- B: Names for the groceries to be indexed by column A;
- C: Check column with "x" for inactive items in column B, empty otherwise;
- D: Sorting indices that I want to apply to column B;

Currently, I am getting the sorted AND filtered result with this formula:

```
=SORT(FILTER(B2:B; C2:C = ""); FILTER(D2:D; C2:C = ""); TRUE)
```

The problem is that I need to apply the filter two times: one for the items and one for the indices, otherwise I get a mismatch between elements for the Sort function.

I feel that this doesn't scale well since it creates duplication.

Is there a way to get the same results with a simpler formula or another arrangement of columns?

Comment: @player0 I added a link to the beginning of the question. The sheets and column names are a bit more complex though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SORT(FILTER({Itens!B2:B\Itens!G2:G}; Itens!D2:D=""))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SORT(FILTER({Itens!B2:B\Itens!G2:G}; Itens!D2:D="");2;1)
```

[image: 0]

---

or maybe: **`=SORT(FILTER(Itens!B2:B; Itens!D2:D="");2;1)`**

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm failing to see how this eliminates duplication, since you still call `FILTER` twice, with the same second parameter. That's the part I find ugly, I would prefer to filter once.

Comment: That's quite interesting! I'm quite new to the Google Sheets syntax, would you mind to explain the  `{}` notation and the `\` notation? How to they work, and why are they used for, here? Then I'll gladly accept your answer!

Comment: sure. `{}` are called array brackets and they are used when you want to create range from columns which are not next to each other. " \ " means to put them next to each other while `;` would mean to put them under each other. you can try it simply by pasting this formula somewhere `={Itens!B2:B\Itens!G2:G}`